React native: Drawer on the home page, stack on all other pages
I would like my app to have a drawer on the main page, and stack navigation on all the rest of the pages. I'm planning on setting out pages so that only some will be accessed from the drawer, others since they contain dynamic routs and/or parameters will only be access by pressing on a generated link outside the drawer.
Please note, I am using expo-router
I have tried nesting them, but each nest has it's own challenges:
The first thing I tried was having just the home page in the app folder, and a _layout which defines drawer navigation, and then having a sub-folder with the pages I want, and in that sub-folder a _layout which defines a stack navigator.
app/
   pages/
      [id].tsx // in this page, there's a link to the page below so when you get there it has a back button which takes you back to this page
      [idInfo].tsx
      nonDynamicPage.tsx
      _layout.tsx // Stack navigator (which hides the header of the drawer navigator)
   index.tsx
   _layout.tsx // Drawer navigator

This worked in that the drawer was showing on the home page, but then when I clicked on a link to a page from the home, the page would open but there would be no back button to get back home. Makes sense since when you open that page, it's technically the beginning of the stack.
Next I tried nesting it the other way. I put the pages with the custom routes and/or parameters in the main app folder with the _layout there defining the stack, then a had a home sub-folder with my home page in it and a _layout which defines a drawer navigator. Then I had the index in the root app folder redirect to to the home folder.
app/
   home/
      index.tsx
      _layout.tsx // Drawer navigator
      nonDynamicPage.tsx // Shows on the drawer
   index.tsx // redirects to home/
   [id].tsx 
   [idInfo].tsx
   _layout.tsx // Stack navigator (which hides the stack header for /home only)

This worked now in that when I started the app, it showed my home page with a drawer, when I clicked on a link with the custom route and/or parameter which directed to the previous folder, it would not show up with a back button that would take me to the home page. The problem was that there would be no back button from any page click on from the drawer, presumably since the line in app/_layout.tsx which disables the stack header (<Stack.Screen name="home" options={{ headerShown: false }} />) disables the header for ALL pages in the home sub-folder.
OK, so the next thing I tried was keeping the same nesting structure as above, except putting a nonDynamicPage in the root app directory and then having the app/home/nonDynamicPage be a redirect to the page in the app folder. This brought the page up but there was no back button on the header. Presumably, the <Redirect> component doesn't push to the stack... (or if not then I don't know what's going on).
The final thing that I tried, was instead of a <Redirect> component, I had the router manually redirect in the body of the function:
export default function RedirectPage() {
    useEffect(() => {
        router.push("/example");
    }, []);
    return <></>;
}

Oddly enough this actually did work... except for that when you press the back button it returns back to the page that redirect right back to this page!!
Oh yeah, at this point I'm out of ideas other than scrapping the use of drawer completely and just replacing the left side of the header bar on the home screen with a button that opens up a modal that covers the left side of the screen and manually displays links to the pages I want

I am having similar issues with expo-router and drawer navigation for dynamic routes.
